# EF Fluent API: Use Two Columns for Descriminator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a fairly simple model inheritance hierarchy that maps to an existing database.

```
public class TestBase
{
    public Int64 Id
}

public class ResultTest : TestBase
{
}

public class BillingTest : TestBase
{
}

public class OrderBase : TestBase
{
}

public class OrderTest : OrderBase
{
}

public class MicroOrderTest : OrderBase
{
}
```

The issue I'm having is trying to map these to our existing database. In our main table TestRevision we have a Type column that indicates the type for BillingTest, ResultTest and OrderBase. Then, in another table, TestRevisionOrder, we have a column that indicates whether an order is of type OrderTest or MicroOrderTest. Is there a way to use EF Fluent API to map this type relationship?

Comment: WHy are you using the same base for the two hierarchies? Can't you implement the Id in an interface, and use two base classes, one for each hierarchy?

Comment: @JotaBe The TestBase class contains the meat of all of our tests. It is also directly represented in the TestRevision table. I'm not sure how changing the type from abstract to interface will change the problem. To be clear, the database already exists, I am mapping to it.

Comment: If you do: `modelBuilder.Entity<ResultTest>().ToTable("ResultTestTableNameInDb"); modelBuilder.Entity<BillingTest>().ToTable("BillingTestTableNameInDB");` doesn't it work?

Comment: I have found that my most pressing issue is that we are trying to do table per type AND table per hierarchy in the same database structure. But either way, my original question was specific to TPH, in which ToTable indicates a TPT approach.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how your tables look like, and which mapppings you need. Can you add info about columns and mappings? I don't understandhow many different tables there are, and which discriminators have to be used.